# AJAX CORS request fails although my server enables headers - (Access-Control*)

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, cors

I have a NodeJS server that is supposed to handle CORS DELETE requests.
I have a middleware express layer:

```
app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" , "http://myhost.com");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE, OPTIONS");   
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
});

app.delete('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('OK');
});
```

My AJAX call is

```
$.ajax({ url:"http://myhost.com", type:'DELETE'})

  .done(function(resp){  
            document.body.innerHTML = resp;  
        })  
  .fail(function(jqXHR, error, errorThrown){  
            document.body.innerHTML = "Failed to make AJAX request";  
        })
```

In Chrome, I see

> Failed to make AJAX request

If I open webkit inspector:

> Console: ... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin: "http://myhost.com" is therefore not allowed access.

I also see the OPTIONS request returns the valid 'Access-Control-Allow*' headers:

> Access-Control-Allow-Methods:DELETE, OPTIONS
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://myhost.com

However, if I inspect the final HTTP DELETE request, after the Options request in the network tab, I see 'OK' - returned from my server

NOTE: I only see this on Firefox and Chrome. Seems to work on IE

Comment: Preflights don't always get sent. In situations where they aren't, said headers must be on the primary request.

Comment: try out CORS extension on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

The CORS specification requires the server to set headers on the actual request (the `DELETE`) as well as the preflight request (the `OPTIONS`).

See [section 6.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-requests) for the details, but in your case simply adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header should do it.

Comment: I'd really like to understand why your answer was downvoted.  Isn't this accurate?